# Custom JSON serilization on the Ok() function .NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, string, http, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# .NET WebAPI project and all my API are of the form:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
   var myComplexObject = BuildResponse();

   return Ok(myComplexObject);
}
```

The `Ok()` function is currently responsible for serializing the response object into a JSON string. How can I tell the framework to use a custom JSON serializer rather than the default one?

Comment: For only this request or for all requests?

Comment: Why don't you use `return Json(myComplexObject)` since this returns also status 200 / OK?

Comment: @CodeCaster for all of them

Comment: @hakany I want to define my custom JSON serializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use custom serializer for all requests then configure `HttpConfiguration` in WebApiConfig.cs

```
// Add custom formatter - add at the top so it fires first!
// This leaves the old one in place so JsonValue/JsonObject/JsonArray still are handled
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new CustomJsonNetFormatter());
```

Here is an article on how to make your own serailizer

[Using an alternate JSON Serializer in ASP.NET Web API](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/mar/09/using-an-alternate-json-serializer-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

Instance of returning by calling OK() method, you can create new  OkNegotiatedContentResult. from there you put your JsonSerializerSettings.

Actually, when you call OK(T content) method, it will help you create new OkNegotiatedContentResult object. and it will wrap your response object there. So you can it directly.
Hope it helps.

Comment: But then you actually bypass content negotiation, and hardcode JSON support.